# How to get saved credit card number and expire date using STRIPE

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am using **stripe** in Android for credit card payment. Now I want to save the card and retrieve the card's Info like as credit card number and expire date so that I will allow user to pay directly. But I did not get the way for that. please any one have a look on it.

Thanks

Comment: Don't store the information yourself. Use Stripe's [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers) API. Once the customer record is created a customer token is returned. Store this customer token. The customer token is passed in for charges.

Comment: yes I got the customer token **cus_adfasdfasdfz4**. but how could i use it in Android for getting the last 4 digit of card's number and expire date??

Comment: You would retrieve the customer object (https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) on your server and you could look at the `sources` hash associated with it and get the `last4` and expiration date for the card there.